# Дискретное преобразование Фурье на С++. Округляет - в чем дело?

Tags: фурье, c++

Пишу программу, которая раскладывает функцию sin(x) в дискретное преобразование Фурье.
Когда 4-5 точек, то неточно, чем больше, тем точнее, но... до 100. После 100 показывает одинаковые результаты. Однако у моих коллег всё верно.

В файле АЧХ 1-я точка должна быть =1, остальные нулю. Или хотя бы -17 степень. А у меня 0.005, 0.02. Не могу понять, почему.

Пробовала float, setw - не помогло. Также пробовала в Visual Studio 08, 10, 13 - тоже не помогло.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>

const double pi2 = 6.283185307179586;

using namespace std;

int k, i, n, K, N, kol;
double S[1000][2], ugol, Nd, kold, kd, nd;
double a[1000], b[1000], c[1000], fi[1000], m, d, x;
double coord[1000][2];

void main(void)
{

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");//используем русские символы

    int kol;
    cout << "Количество точек=";//ввели количество точек, на которое разбиваем 2п
    cin >> kol;

    kold = kol;

    d = 6.283185307179586 / (kold - 1.0);//разбили интервал на части
    x = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i <(kol+1); i++)
    {   
        coord[i][0] = i;
        coord[i][1] = sin(x); 
        x = x + d;
    }

    fstream f;//обозначили поток f

    f.open("C:\\coord\\coord.txt", fstream::out);//открыли файл
    for (i = 0; i < kol; i++)
        f << coord[i][0] << "   " << coord[i][1]<<"\n";
    f.close();

    cout << "Число гармоник=";
    cin >> K;//число гармоник, на  которые разобьем интервал
        N = 0;//переменная для кол-ва символов. пока =0
    fstream i_f;//обозначили поток f
    i_f.open("C:\\coord\\coord.txt", fstream::in);//открыли файл

    while (!i_f.eof())//пока не конец файла
    {
        i_f >> S[N][0] >> S[N][1];//записываем в файл массив из данных координат
        N++;//число симв в файле
    }
   i_f.close();

N=N-1;
Nd=N;//привели int в double
fstream o_f;//обозначили поток f

    //считаем а и b
    for (k = 0; k<K; k++)
    {kd=k;
        for (n = 0; n<N; n++)
        {nd=n;
            ugol = (pi2*kd*nd)/Nd;

            a[k] = a[k] + (2.0/Nd)*S[n][1]*cos(ugol);//*
        b[k] = b[k] + (2.0/Nd)*S[n][1]*sin(ugol);
        }
        c[k] = sqrt(pow(a[k],2) + pow(b[k],2));
    }
    o_f.close();

    fstream o_f;//обозначили поток f
    o_f.open("C:\\coord\\ачх.txt", fstream::out);//открыли файл     
    for (i = 0; i<K; i++)
    {
        o_f<<c[i]<<"\n";
    }
    o_f.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @AnnGush14, какие параметры используешь? (Гармоники/Точки)

Comment: Пожалуйста, перефразируйте свой вопрос в понятный. ДПФ каких чисел вы делаете? Реальных, комплексных?  С какой целью?  Если с практической,  то может лучше использовать шикарную библиотеку Intel nsp? ДПФ функции sin X дает на выходе единицу,  если результаты нормировать.  С уважением, maxspb.

Comment: кроме b1 все остальные точки должны быть =0, 10^-17 например. а у меня 0.01. -2 степень

Comment: Какая же ублюдочная реализация с рунглишем и глобальными переменными. И ведь в интернете все реализации такие. Видимо, кроме как даунам из вузов этот алгоритм никогда не пригождается.